# Measuring the final timestamp of multiple work items vs one work item in SQL

Tags: sql

I have recently taken over SQL query responsibilities from a colleague who has left.

My question is as follows:
I have 4 work items (A, B, C, D). I have a base population of several thousand cases in which work item D was always the last event. However, in this population, the 2nd to last work item could be A, B, or C. I need to measure, on average, the time between the end of work item A, B, or C and the end of work item item D.  What would this code look like?

Supplementary information: The pertinent tables I would join:

1. Database.workitems (identifies work item a b c d)
2. Database.workitemstatus (show possible statuses - open, in progress, complete - of work items)
3. Database.workitemsstatustime (gives the timestamp for work item status inserts)

So I think my FROM statement would be

```
FROM database.basepopulation BP --this table had one column, case number
Inner Join database.workitems WI ON BP.casenumber = WI.casenumber -- this gives me work items A,B,C,D
Inner Join database.workitemstatus WIS ON WI.workitemID = WIS.workitemID -- this gives me the statuses open, in progress, complete
Inner Join database.workitemstatustime WIST ON WIS.statusinsertdate = WI.dateID -- gives me the timestamps of the status inserts
```

So I think I have what I need to start.  The base population established every case number ended in work item D.  Now I must measure the average time between work item status = complete for any other work item (A,B,C) and work item status = complete for work item D.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They aren't the same.

Comment: @ElGato64 . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Only tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: We really could use better information -- examples of the data in the tables.

Comment: `Inner Join database.workitemstatustime WIST ON WIS.statusinsertdate = WI.dateID` this doesn't make a lot of sense.  WIST has no join criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plenty of guessing going on here . . .
workitemstatustime seems redundant?  You'll need to provide columns of the tables for us to understand. **untested** but maybe this will help you figure something out.

```
select BP.*, WIS.dateID DCompletion, secondtolast.previousCompletion,
   datediff(day,previousCompletion, WIS.dateID) / count(*) AverageDays
from basepopulation BP
inner join ( -- this subquery gets the maximum completed date that isn't from item D
   select WI.casenumber, max(WI.dateID) previousCompletion -- Guessing that dateID is the 
   completion date
   from workitems WI
   Inner Join workitemstatus WIS
      ON WI.workitemID = WIS.workitemID
      and WIS.status='Completed' -- I'm totally guessing at this
   where WI.Item <> 'D' -- Another total guess
   group by WI.casenumber
) secondtolast on secondtolast.casenumber = BP.casenumber
inner join workitems WI ON BP.casenumber = WI.casenumber
Inner Join workitemstatus WIS ON WI.workitemID = WIS.workitemID
where WIS.status = 'Completed' -- I'm guessing here
   and WI.Item = 'D' -- another guess
```

Comment: thank you so much!  This architecture worked perfectly after a few tweaks.  I never would have that to join a subquery in on the base data